# In Exact Matching in Causal Inference, why is it that that $P(X_i=x\mid Z_i = 1)= P(X_i=x\mid Z_i = 0)$ where $X,Z$ are the covariates and treatment?

Tags: causality, matching

In Exact Matching in Causal Inference, I read that because we assume exact matches, then exact balance occurs in the distribution of the covariates. It is then often stated that if $X,Z$ are the covariates and treatment, respectively,

$$
P(X_i=x\mid Z_i = 1)= P(X_i=x\mid Z_i = 0)
$$

for all units $i$ in a population.

I am wondering why this is the case. In which sense does exact balance imply such a condition holding on the conditional distributions?

A reference is in pg. 173 [here](http://www.mattblackwell.org/files/teaching/causal-i-slides.pdf).

Comment: Please give proper citation to what you read, with a quote of the relevant material.  May we assume that $Z_i$ is binary?

Comment: @ Ben, Yes, I am assuming $Z_i$ is binary. I have added the citation.

Comment: Suppose all the treated observations are male and all the control observations are female. How can you do exact matching in that case?

Comment: For matching on gender, I would assume that we cannot find such exact matching pairs? Does that imply the equation above does not hold?

Comment: It implies that $P(X_i=F\mid Z_i = 1)= 0 \ne P(X_i=F\mid Z_i = 0)=1$.

Comment: Does this imply the probability here is the sample proportion? I had assumed the conditional probability might be the underlying population distribution for the covariates. Is such an assumption wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact matching means that for each unit with some covariate value $x$ in the treated group (i.e., $Z=1$), one (assuming 1:1 matching) unit with the same covariate value $x$ in the control group (i.e., $Z=0$) is selected to be part of the matched sample. Therefore, the empirical distribution of the covariate in the treated group is identical to the empirical distribution of the covariate in the control group.

If $P(X_i=x|Z_i=z)$ is taken to mean that the probability that a random individual $i$ drawn from the group $Z=z$ has covariate value $x$, then, because the proportion of individuals in each treatment group with that level of the covariate is the same, these probabilities will be equal in the groups.

Consider the example with gender (as mentioned in the comments). Let's say initially your treated group is 30% men and 70% women. Exact matching involves creating a matched control group from a pool of potential controls whereby each unit in the treated group is matched to a control unit with the same covariate value. So, after exact matching, we have a matched control group that is also 30% men and 70% women. The probability of randomly drawing a man from the treated group is equal to the probability of randomly drawing a man from the control group. Or, said another way, the probability that any individual is a man in the treated group is equal to the probability that any individual is a man in the control group. This is precisely what your original statement says.

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies things. I originally kept thinking that if the conditional probabilities were the same, it implied a 50-50 % split. However, I see that with your 30-70 example, it is not the same, and that the idea is to keep the treated/control groups the same in probability. Thank you!